# Get a zone situated x minutes from a point (based on direction, not geographical distance)

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, mapbox, turfjs

I am trying to replicate what [turf.js buffer](http://turfjs.org/examples/turf-buffer/) does but based on direction time (1) rather than distance (2). Can't find anything neither in [Mapbox direction API](https://www.mapbox.com/api-documentation/#distance) nor turf.js doc. Am I missing something?

*(1) get the zone around a point that takes 20mn by car to reach*

*(2) get the zone 20km around a point*

Answer (score 0):

This is called isochrone calculation. See here for more information

- https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Isochrone where several productive services are included
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isochrone_map

Comment: Amazing! Thanks for that.

Comment: @Karussell is the graph always loaded on memory or a spatial database ?